# Elfeed: mark all messages as read

Tags: elfeed

Is it possible to mark all unread messages as read with a single key? <kbd>r</kbd> marks only the selected message as read.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can select the whole buffer and mark everything as read using the <kbd>r</kbd> default binding in `elfeed-search-mode-map`.

You can also write a little function like below:

```
(defun elfeed-mark-all-as-read ()
      (interactive)
      (mark-whole-buffer)
      (elfeed-search-untag-all-unread))
```

and bind that to <kbd>R</kbd> in `elfeed-search-mode-map` if you wish.

```
(define-key elfeed-search-mode-map (kbd "R") 'elfeed-mark-all-as-read)
```

*Note that at the time of writing this, this mapping was unused in `elfeed-search-mode-map`.*